# Using d3, how can I create a histogram or bar plot where the last bar is the count of all values greater than some number?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, histogram, bar-chart, axis

Code link: https://plnkr.co/edit/jLkoMxdzArBBULHF80nb?p=preview

I have a data with some disperse values. It ranges from 61 to 1.2m.

[image]

How can I represent it in a Histogram in a way that makes sense?
Can I have the last bucket on d3 that is `> 2000` for instance?

Something like this (greater than 5 minutes):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**First** of all you will need to arrange your data (if you haven't yet), where you just need to create a variable with the `> 2000` values.

This is the way I did it (I started `d3` last week and I don't have any previous knowledge on `JavaScript`, so there's probably a better way to do it):

```
var data = [];

for (var i = 0; i < oldData.length; ++i) {
  if (oldData[i] >= 2000) {
    data[i] = 2000;
  }
  else data[i] = oldData[i];
}
```

---

**Next** thing, is o set manually the ticks you want and the tickLabels that correspond to it:

```
var ticks = [0,200,400,600,800,1000,1200,1400,1600,1800,2000];
var tickLabels = [0,200,400,600,800,1000,1200,1400,1600,1800,"> 2000"];
```

(notice that you can change to "1,200" and so on if you want the separator)

And instead of calling the `d3.axisBottom(x)` directly to your chart, I like to create a separate `xAxis` variable, and set the ticks and tickLabels to it:

```
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
              .tickValues(ticks)
              .tickFormat(function(d,i){ return tickLabels[i] });
```

---

**Finally** you call the `xAxis` on your chart:

```
chart.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);
```

Comment: Thanks @TheBiro for looking into it. I tried you suggestions and the ones on your link without luck. If you can think in a way to solve the problem you fork this example https://plnkr.co/edit/jLkoMxdzArBBULHF80nb

Comment: I didn't see the link to your code before, but now I could do it, I'll update my answer with the right answer.